# Counting records in JSON array using javascript and Postman

Tags: javascript, json, postman

I have a control that returns 2 records:

```
{
  "value": [
    {
      "ID": 5,
      "Pupil": 1900031265,
      "Offer": false,
    },
    {
      "ID": 8,
      "Pupil": 1900035302,
      "Offer": false,
      "OfferDetail": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to test via Postman, that I have 2 records returned.  I've tried various methods I've found here and elsewhere but with no luck.  Using the code below fails to return the expected answer.

```
responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var list = responseBody.length;
tests["Expected number"] = list === undefined || list.length === 2;
```

At this point I'm  not sure if it's the API I'm testing that's at fault or my coding - I've tried looping through the items returned but that's not working for me either.  Could someone advise please - I'm new to javascript so am expecting there to be an obvious cause to my problem but I'm failing to see it.  Many thanks.

Comment: `responseJson` is a object read the key `value` and then `length`

Comment: Your json array has a length of 1 object named "value" but your "value" object should have a length of 2. Check `responseJson.value` length instead.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Correct your json. and try this.

=======================v

```
var test = JSON.parse('{"value": [{"ID": 5,"Pupil": 1900031265,"Offer": false},{"ID": 8,"Pupil": 1900035302,"Offer": false,"OfferDetail": ""}] }')
    
test.value.length; // 2
```

So you need to identify the array in the json (starting with the `[` bracket. and then take the key and then check the `length` of the `key`.

Answer (score 54):

In postman, under `Tests` section, do the following (screenshot below):

  `var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
  tests["Count: "  + body.value.length] = true;`

Here is what you should see (note: I replaced `responseBody` with JSON to mock up example above):
[image]

Comment: I add this to a large response and it never returns, just sits saying Loading for hours and hours.

Comment: @ConnieDeCinko I have done this for large data and this code works for me
```var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Count: "  + body.length] = true;```

Answer (score 25):

Here's the simplest way I figured it out:

```
pm.expect(Object.keys(pm.response.json()).length).to.eql(18);
```

No need to customize any of that to your variables. Just copy, paste, and adjust "18" to whatever number you're expecting.

Comment: I've get: AssertionError: expected 3 to deeply equal 10

Comment: @liquide That probably simply means that your test is correctly failing. It doesn't mean that the test is wrong.

Answer (score 10):

This is what I did for counting the recods

```
//parsing the Response body to a variable
    responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);

//Finding the length of the Response Array
    var list = responseJson.length;
    console.log(list);
    tests["Validate service retuns 70 records"] = list === 70;
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

More updated version of asserting only 2 objects in an array:

```
pm.test("Only 2 objects in array", function (){
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().length).to.eql(2);
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Your response body is an object you cannot find the length of an object try

```
var list = responseJson.value.length;
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should convert response to json and find value path. Value is array. You should call to length function to get how many objects in there and check your expected size

```
pm.test("Validate value count", function () {
    pm.expect(pm.response.json().value.length).to.eq(2);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, what I used to test for a certain number of array members is:

```
responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Response Body = []"] = responseJson.length === valueYouAreCheckingFor;
```

To check what values you're getting, print it and check the postman console.

```
console.log(responseJson.length);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Counting records in JSON array using javascript and insomnia**

```js
//response insomnia
const response = await insomnia.send();

//Parse Json
const body = JSON.parse(response.data);

//Print console:
console.log(body.data.records.length);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
 pm.test("Only 2 objects in array", function (){
     var jsonData = pm.response.json();
     let event_length = jsonData.data.length;
    pm.expect(event_length).to.eql(2);
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should test `responseJson.value.length`

`responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
tests["Expected number"] = typeof responseJson === 'undefined' || responseJson.value.length;`

Answer (score -1):

I was facing similar issue while validating the length of an array inside a JSON. The below snippet should help you resolve it-

```
responseJson = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var list = responseBody.length;
tests["Expected number"] = responseJson.value.length === list;
```

Answer (score -1):

Working Code

```
 pm.test("Verify the number of records",function()
 {
   var response = JSON.parse(responseBody); 
   pm.expect(Object.keys(response.value).length).to.eql(5);

 });
//Please change the value in to.eql function as per your requirement    
//'value' is the JSON notation name for this example and can change as per your JSON
```